# Is there a way to sum 2 ranges instead of just 2 cells?

Tags: excel, vba, sum, range

i am trying to sum column "e" and column "f"

instead of

> ("e1")=("e1")+("f1")

i would like to see something like the following.

```
set Range1 as range("E1:E100")
set Range2 as range ("f1:f100")

Range1=Range1+Range2
```

i know it wont work like this but believe there has t be way to get the results.

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you expecting 1 number or 100 numbers?

Comment: i expect 100 numbers

Comment: Please never use ALL CAPS this is considered screaming.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below code :

```
With Range("g1:g100")
    .Formula = "=e1+f1"
End With
```

Comment: Sub Sum_EF()


 With Range("z17:z116")
    .Formula = "=e17+f17"
End With
 Range("e17:e116").Value = Range("z17:z116").Value
  
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

You can use Evaluate:

```
Dim ws as worksheet, Range1 as range, Range2 as range

set Range1 as ws.range("E1:E100")
set Range2 as ws.range ("f1:f100")

Range1.value = ws.Evaluate( Range1.Address() & "+" & Range2.address() )
```